# Downloading AWS S3 file with python boto returns 404 even though file exists

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, boto

I'm using Python boto module for accessing AWS S3 files.
I unload files from Redshift with UNLOAD commands and files are automatically gzipped. Redshift generates 10 parts of one file.

This is the part of the code I use to get the file list and call the download function:

```
key_list = bucket.list('folder_on_the_bucket')
pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)
partial_download = partial(download,0)
pool.map(partial_download, key_list)
```

This is the download function:

```
def download(retry_cnt,key):
retry_cnt = retry_cnt
key = key
try:
    #make sure that I download only files, not folders
    if key.name[-1]=='/' or key.name[-1]=='\\':
        pass
    else:
        log.info("Downloading %s" % local_dir+ntpath.basename(key.name))
        key.get_contents_to_filename(local_dir+ntpath.basename(key.name))
        if retry_cnt > 0:
            #copy all files that needed to be retried to a specific directory (for debugging purposes)
            shutil.copyfile(local_dir+ntpath.basename(key.name), 'error_files_folder'+ntpath.basename(key.name))
except:
    if retry_cnt < 3:
        retry_cnt += 1
        log.warning("error downloading file %s, retrying for the %s. time" % (str(key.name),str(retry_cnt)))
        log.warning(str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
        time.sleep(5)
        download(retry_cnt,key)
    else:
        log.error(sys.exc_info()[1])
        sys.exit("Unable to download file")
```

The issue is that sometimes, AWS will return 404 error, the file doesn't exist. I've checked manually and the file apperas in S3 bucket and it has data. 
I've read that it's possible for S3 to return such error if the changes haven't been propagated. That's why the download functions looks like this. If an error occurs with the file, I'll try to download the same file again. Problem is that the second time I download the file, it's empty and I lose some of the data. (one tenth of it).

This problem occurs randomly on different buckets and folders.

Comment: Another option is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to download the files using the `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp --recursive` commands.

Comment: I could use that inside the download function but do you think that it could resolve the 404 error? The way I figured it is that the error happens on AWS side, not on Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing the way download function works. I removed try from there and set it around the part of the code calling it.

```
def get_download_files():
    global key_list
    key_list = bucket.list(s3_full_path)
    for f in key_list:
        log.info(f)
    try:
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)
        pool.map(download, key_list)
    except:
        log.warning("error occured while downloading")
        log.warning(sys.exc_info()[1])
        global error_cnt
        error_cnt = 1
        pass
```

By using this function, I can make sure that if any of the files fails to download for any reason, I'll set error_cnt to 1 indicating that there's been a problem. After that I have a function that retries to download entire folder again for three times before throwing system error and failing entire process.